# R argument is of length zero when using names(vector) in IF statement

Tags: r, if-statement, compiler-errors

I have a dataframe and a vector like this:

```
# sample data
IDd= c(seq(1,8))
BTD= c("A","B","AB","O","AB","AB","O","O")
fg= c(rep(0.0025, each=2),rep(0.00125, each=2),rep(0.0011, each=2),rep(0.0015, each=2))
data_D=data.frame(IDd,BTD,A=c(rep(0,5),1,1,1),B=c(rep(0,6),1,1),C=c(rep(1,7),0),D=rep(1,8),E=c(rep(0,5),rep(1,2),0),fg,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

data_D
  IDd BTD A B C D E      fg
2   2   A 0 0 1 1 0 0.00250
4   4  AB 0 0 1 1 0 0.00125
5   5   B 0 0 1 1 0 0.00110
6   6   O 0 0 1 1 0 0.00110
7   7  AB 0 0 1 1 0 0.00150
8   8  AB 1 0 1 1 1 0.00150
1   1   O 1 1 0 1 0 0.00250
3   3   O 1 1 1 1 1 0.00125

# character vector 
Rvec=c(1,"A",0,0,0,0,1,0.0031)
names(Rvec)=c("Idr","BTR","A","B","C","D","E","fg")
Rvec
     Idr      BTR        A        B        C        D        E       fg 
     "1"      "A"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "1" "0.0031"
```

Everytime i want to check names of my vector or dataframe i got an error. Here is the code

```
check.names=function(Rvec,Data){ 
  Rvec=as.vector(Rvec)
  Data=as.data.frame(Data)
if(names(Data)[3:ncol(Data)] != names(Rvec)[3:length(Rvec)]) stop("Error")
if(names(Rvec)[2] != "BTR") {
  names(Rvec)[2] = "BTR" 
 }
}

check.names(Rvec= Rvec, Data=data_D)
# Error in if (names(Data)[3:ncol(Data)] != names(Rvec)[3:length(Rvec)])
 # stop("Error") : 
 # argument is of length zero
```

I keep getting this error whenever i used `names` in both `if` statement. Do you know what cause this problem?
I also took a look at ["argument is of length zero" in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883759/argument-is-of-length-zero-in-if-statement), [r if statement meet error: argument is of length zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796978/r-if-statement-meet-error-argument-is-of-length-zero), but still can not resolve this issue. The weird thing is when i run the `if` statement separately i do not get any errors but once within the function i get the error message.
Thank you for your help .

@DanY, i just modified the line `all.equal` in your answer and it is working now

```
# first modified vector
 names(Rvec)[2]="btr"
 names(Rvec)[3]="k"
 Rvec
     Idr      btr        k        B        C        D        E       fg 
     "1"      "A"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "1" "0.0031" 

# second modified vector 
Rvec1
     Idr      btr        A        B        C        D        E       fg 
     "1"      "A"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "0"      "1" "0.0031" 
# modified function

check.names=function(Rvec,Data){
  if(!is.vector(Rvec)) stop("Rvec must be a vector")
  if(!is.data.frame(Data)) stop("Data must be a data.frame")
  dnames <- names(Data)[3:ncol(Data)]
  rnames <- names(Rvec)[3:length(Rvec)]
  if(!isTRUE(all.equal(dnames, rnames))) stop("Names don't match")
  if(names(Rvec)[2] != "BTR") {
    names(Rvec)[2] = "BTR" 
  }  
  
}

# test for first modified vector Rvec
check.names(Rvec= Rvec, Data=data_D)
# Error in check.names(Rvec = Rvec, Data = data_D) : Names don't match

# test for second modified vector Rvec1
a=check.names(Rvec= Rvec1, Data=data_D)
a
[1] "BTR"
```

Comment: `if(names(data)[3:ncol(data)]`  R is case sensitive `data != Data`

Comment: I corrected it but still get the same error, do you have any idea why ? @SteveM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function uses the line

```
Rvec = as.vector(Rvec)
```

The help documentation for `as.vector()` states that "if the result is atomic, all attributes are removed." This means that element names are dropped when you run `as.vector()`.

One solution is not to *coerce* Rvec to be a vector, but rather to *check* that it is a vector.  You'll also need to change the `if()` statement in your third line to either an `ifelse()` or an `all.equal()`. Here's one solution with those 2 fixes (replace the ... with the rest of your code):

```
check.names <- function(Rvec,Data){ 
    if(!is.vector(Rvec)) stop("Rvec must be a vector")
    if(!is.data.frame(Data)) stop("Data must be a data.frame")
    
    dnames <- names(Data)[3:ncol(Data)]
    rnames <- names(Rvec)[3:length(Rvec)]
    
    if(!all.equal(dnames, rnames)) stop("Names don't match")
    ...
}
```

Comment: Now @DanY  i get  the message: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` (when i removed the first 2 lines in the function and replace it with your `if` cheks) ??

Comment: OMG @DanY now i get a different error message `Error in all.equal.default(dnames == rnames) :  argument "current" is missing, with no default `  when add `if(!all.equal(dnames==rnames)) stop("Names don't match")`. I dont understand i dont have any argument called `current`?

Comment: Sure thing i learned a lot from you! i thank you very much for your patience @DanY! It seems to work, i will test it with different vector right now!

Comment: When i try a different vector with different names i dont get `stop()` message, instead i get this error message `Error in !all.equal(dnames, rnames) : invalid argument type`.

Comment: it is working now @DanY, i just changed `!all.equal(dnames, rnames)` to `isTrue(all.equal(dnames, rnames))`

Comment: Thank you @DanY for your help, really appreciate it!